# How to calculate the Yeserday, last 7 days, this week till day, this month till day user logged count in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to calculate the user logged in count on system.

In my table i have

Id, TRANSDATE now i want to calculate the measure on four categories

which are yesterday, last 7 days, this week till day, this month till day count.

```
Yesterday = 

CONCATENATE(
    CONCATENATE(
        "Yesterday Count",
        UNICHAR(10)
    ), " (" & 
    FORMAT(TODAY - 1, "DD-MMM") 
    & ")"
)

﻿﻿Last 7  Days =  

CONCATENATEN(
        CONCATENATE(
            "Last 7 Days  Count",UNICHAR(10)
        ), 
    " (" &  
        FORMAT(TODAY() - 7,"DD-MMM") 
    & " to " & 
        FORMAT(TODAY() - 1,"DD-MMM") &")" 
)


This Week till date = 

CONCATENATE(
    CONCATENATE(
        “This Week till date Count”,
        UNICHAR(16)
    ), SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        FORMAT(
            if (
            WEEKDAY(TODAY(),1) == 1, 
            TODAY(),
            TODAY() - (WEEKDAY(TODAY(),1) - 1))
        ,"DD-MMM") == 
        FORMAT(TODAY(),"DD-MMM"), " ("& 
        FORMAT{TODAY() ,"DD-MMM") &“)", 
        FORMAT(
            if (
            WEEKDAY(TODAY(),1) == 1, 
            TODAY(),
            TODAY() - (WEEKDAY(TODAY(),1) - 1)
        ),"DD-MMM") <> 
        FORMAT(TODAY(),"DD-MMM")," ("&
        FORMAT(
            if(
            WEEKDAY(TODAY(),1) == 1, 
            TODAY(),
            TODAY() - (WEEKDAY{TODAY(),1) - 1)
        ),"DD-MMN") &" to “& 
        FORMAT(TODAY(), "DD-MMM") &")"
)

This Month till date = 

CONCATENATE(
    CONCATENATE(
        "This Month till date Count”,
        UNICHAR(10)
    ), SWITCH(
        TRUE() ,
        FORMAT(DATE(
            YEAR(TODAY()),
            MONTH(TODAY()),
            1),
            "DD-MMM"
        ) == 
        FORMAT(
            TODAY(),
            "DD-MMM"
        ), “ ("& 
        FORMAT(
            TODAY(),
            "DD-MMM"
        ) &")", 
        FORMAT(
            DATE(
            YEAR(TODAY()),
            MONTH(TODAY())
            ,1
            ),
            "DD-MMM") <> 
            FORMAT(
                TODAY(),
                "DD-MMM"
            )," ("& 
            FORMAT(
                DATE(
                YEAR(TODAY()),
                MONTH(TODAY()),
                1),
                "DD-MMM") &" to “& 
                FORMAT(
                TODAY() , 
                "DD-MMM" &") "
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved in this following way

```
YesterdayM = 

CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('user’[Id]),
        FILTER('user’, [TRANSDATE] = TODAY() - 1)
    ) + 0


LastSevenDaysM = 

CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(‘user’[Id]),
        FILTER(‘user‘,[TRANSDATE] >= (TODAY() - 7) && [TRANSDATE] < TODAY())
    ) + 0 


CurrentWeekTillDateM = 

CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT( 'user’ [Id]),
        FILTER(’user',[TRANSDATE] >= 
            if(
            WEEKDAY(TODAY(),1) == 1, 
            TODAY(),
            TODAY() - (WEEKDAY(TODAY(),1) - 1)
            )
        )
) + 0


CurrentMonthTillDateM = 

CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(‘user‘ [Id]),
        FILTER(‘user‘, [TRANSDATE] >= 
        DATE(
        YEAR(TODAY()),
        MONTH(TODAY())
        ,1)
) + 0
```